# topfigrule only for figure but not for tables

Tags: tables

My tables have the captions above and are set with `booktabs`'s `\bottomrule` at the end. I would like to separate figure (having their caption below) from the text with a `\topfigrule`

```
\newcommand{\topfigrule}{\hrule}
```

*but* not for tables, as they are already separated enough by the `\bottomrule`.

How can I configure `\topfigrule` to be active only for figures?

Assume that there is always only one float at the top of the page, either a table *or* a figure.

MWE: first page with table, second page with figure. The first page should not get a topfigrule.

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading]{scrbook}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\topfigrule}{\vspace{0.5cm}\hrule}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.5cm}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{table}
  \caption{Foo}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
    \toprule
     1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\\midrule
     a & b & c & d & e\\
     \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\clearpage

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Bar}
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX doesn't normally keep track of float type at that point, but you can make it remember the last type it saw and then make the rule conditional on that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@comflelt#1{%
{\count@\count#1\divide\count@32 \xdef\lasttype{\the\count@}}%
\setbox\@tempboxa
      \vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa\box #1\vskip\floatsep}}

\newcommand{\topfigrule}{\ifnum\lasttype=1\hrule\fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
aaa

\begin{table}[t]\caption{ccc} xxx\end{table}

bbb

\newpage

aaa

\begin{figure}[t]xxx \caption{kkk}\end{figure}

bbb

\end{document}
```